# sorting in django admin list by a custom field alphabetically

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

I have a simple store / product relationship and I want to sort the products depending on the store name alphabetically.

models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    show_name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128, null = True, blank = True)

class Product(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

and in the admin:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["number", "name", "get_store_name",]
    
    def get_store_name(self, obj):
        if obj.store.show_name == None:
            return f"""{obj.store.name}"""
        else:
            return f"""{obj.store.show_name}"""
```

I know I cannot use `order_by` on custom fields. So I thought I need to override the `get_queryset` method probably? I found multiple examples to annotate by counted or calculated numbers, but never for strings.

Comment: try `queryset.order_by('store__name')`

Comment: The keyword `store` cannot be resolved. I know this example is pretty basic, but I intentionally asked for string-sorting, as my logic sometimes changes the valur returned. I updated my example to show that.

Comment: In model that you show `Store` model has no `show_name` field, so this line `f"""{obj.store.show_name}"""` wouldn't work

Comment: yes, this was a very poor edit of mine. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for edit, does my answer satisfy your question? @xtlc

Comment: It actually does. Can you have a look at my more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73773465/annotation-in-admin-list-with-many-to-many-relation

Comment: Glad to hear, consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. Okay, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate field with condition to queryset and then, set it as `ordering` in `@admin.display` decorator for your custom field.

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, When


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["number", "name", "get_store_name"]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _store_name=Case(
                When(store__show_name__isnull=True, then=F('store__name')),
                default=F('store__show_name')),
            ),
        )
        return queryset

    @admin.display(ordering='_store_name')
    def get_store_name(self, obj):
        if obj.store.show_name:
            return obj.store.show_name
        return obj.store.name
```

With this implementation, standard django admin interface sorting will work for your column

[image]

If you want just default sorting, you can add it to queryset before return in `get_queryset()`

```
queryset.order_by('_store_name')
```